# inject $scope and promise result into controller constructor using angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am using [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I need to inject `$scope` and some pre-fetched data into my controller`s constructor.

I am able to achieve this when I only add the promise to the resolve object, as soon as I add the `$scope` service to the list of injectables angular ui router fails to resolve the route.

working typescript code:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    template: 'I am the child state',
    controller: 'TestController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {                
        viewModel:initializeControllerViewModel
    }
});

initializeControllerViewModel.$inject = [
    '$stateParams',
    '$q',
    '$timeout'
];

function initializeControllerViewModel(
    $stateParams: ng.ui.IStateParamsService,
    $q: ng.IQService,
    $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService)
{
    let deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(() =>
    {
        deferred.resolve({
            property1: 'foo'
        });
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise;    
}

class TestController
{
    constructor(
        viewModel: any)
    {            
        //viewModel should be {property1: 'foo'}
    }
}
```

Not working code:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/child',
    template: 'I am the child state',
    controller: 'TestController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        '$scope': '$scope',
        viewModel:initializeControllerViewModel
    }
});

class TestController
{
    constructor(
        $scope: ng.IScope,
        viewModel: any)
    {
        //$scope should be injected
        //viewModel should be {property1: 'foo'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove scope from ui router and try using $inject property in your class

```
class TestController
{
public static $inject = ['$scope', 'viewModel'];
constructor(
        $scope: ng.IScope,
        viewModel: any)
    {
        //$scope should be injected
        //viewModel should be {property1: 'foo'}
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before and then the `$scope` variable is properly injected but the `viewModel` has a value of `undefined`

Comment: Did you add 'viewModel' to $inject?

Comment: no I did not, adding it solved the issue, please update your answer then I will accept it